# Salvar no banco de dados uma coluna do datagrid

Tags: c#, mysql

Preciso pegar o valor da coluna desconto do meu `datagrid` e salvar no meu banco de dados, será que consigo, ele é calculado quando registro o consumo de acordo com a quantidade, segue abaixo o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
foreach (var leitura in leituras)
{
    totalConsumo += leitura.Consumo;
    totalDesconto += leitura.Desconto;
}

dgv[0, dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Value = "Total";
dgv[1, dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Value = totalConsumo.ToString();
dgv[2, dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Value = totalDesconto.ToString();
lblResultado.Text = "Total consumo com desconto: " + (totalConsumo - totalDesconto).ToString();
```

**Código de persistência**

```
    CONEXAO.Open(); 
    MySqlCommand INSERT = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO consumo (casa, consumo)" + "VALUES ('" + casa + "','" + consumo + "')", CONEXAO);
    INSERT.Parameters.AddWithValue(casa, txtCasa.Text); 
    INSERT.Parameters.AddWithValue(consumo, txtConsumo.Text); 
    INSERT.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    MessageBox.Show("O registro foi inserido com sucesso !");
```

Comment: Se o desconto vem de acordo com registro de consumo, é só você pegar o valor final que tiver na variável de controle totalDesconto e adicionar ela ao objeto da classe que quer salvar.

Comment: O mesmo padrão lógico que se usa pra popular o objeto pode ser utilizado para enviar os dados pro banco. A estrutura de repetição e acesso por índice.

Comment: @Diógenes Edite a sua pergunta para incluir o código nela, não nos comentários.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, obrigado pela dica !